# Add header to multiple CSV files

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm looking for a way to add a header line into multiple CSV files.
Problem with this code below is that it will add an extra empty row at the end of each file. I don't understand why there is extra empty line but I need to delete those lines.

```psh
$header="Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6"
Get-ChildItem .\ -Recurse -Filter *.csv| Foreach-Object {
  $header+"`r`n"+ (Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String) |
    Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: `Get-ChildItem .\ -Recurse -Filter *.csv| Foreach-Object { @($header;Get-Content $_.FullName) | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName}`

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way would be to import the files specifying the headers and then re-export them:

```psh
$header = 'Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', 'Column5', 'Column6'

Get-ChildItem .\ -Recurse -Filter '*.csv' | ForEach-Object {
  $file = $_.FullName
  (Import-Csv -Path $file -Header $header) | Export-Csv -Path $file -NoType
}
```

`Export-Csv` does add double quotes around all fields of the CSV, though. Also, parsing the data into objects does have a performance impact. If you don't want the double quotes added or are pressed for performance the solution suggested by @PetSerAl in the comments to your question might be a better approach for you:

```psh
$header = 'Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6'

Get-ChildItem .\ -Recurse -Filter '*.csv' | ForEach-Object {
  $file = $_.FullName
  @($header; Get-Content -Path $file) | Set-Content -Path $file
}
```

Comment: @Ansgar.Thank you. PetSerAl solution works best for me.